# Multiple pattern matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

As of now, I'm using the method found below to test patterns against statements, but I'm wondering how I should approach/attempt matching multiple patterns versus a single statement.

Should I store the patterns in an array and match them versus the statement, or is there a more efficient (and maybe less complicated) way of doing so?

```
public class StringConvenience {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        String pattern = ".*Q[^u]\\d+\\..*";
        String line = "Order QT300. Now!";

        if (line.matches(pattern)) {
            System.out.println(line + " matches \"" + pattern + "\"");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your own suggestion? What happens?

Comment: Yes, your approach is reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not such hard. Just use an array and for-loop. It's effective and simple.

```
String line = "Order QT300. Now!";
String[] pattern = new String[3];
pattern[0] = ".*Q[^u]\\d+\\..*";
pattern[1] = ".*?";
pattern[2] = "ABC";

for (String pat : pattern) {
    if (line.matches(pat)) {
        System.out.println(line + " matches \"" + pat + "\"");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
}
```

Comment: Although good solution. It might be better to use precompiled regexes. Might give a performance gain.